# regex to match a username with no consecutive spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, spaces

I am struggling to make a javascript regex to satisfy the following:

1. The first character has to be alphabetical (`[a-zA-Z]`)
2. The rest can be any letters, any numbers, hyphen, dot, underscore and spaces
3. **BUT no consecutive spaces,** e.g: two or more spaces in a row
4. The length has to be between 3 and 25 (inclusive)

So here is what I found [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/oD3jD3/1):

```
/^[a-z][\s\w.-]{3,24}$/i
```

My current regex works, but won't be able to test whether the user has written consecutive spaces. How can I test for that?

Comment: As in, trailing spaces, or consecutive spaces?

Comment: consecutives, i don't want consecutives spaces at all. he can write simple spaces where he wants except first character (has to be a-z)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
/^[a-z](?!.* {2})[ \w.-]{2,24}$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD3jD3/2)